# Replace a sentence with another using unix

Tags: unix

I need to replace the whole line which contains `<ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Automatically recover terminated tasks" VALUE ="NO"/>` with `<ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Automatically recover terminated tasks" VALUE ="YES"/>`. Sample file is as below:

```
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Write Backward Compatible Workflow Log File" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Workflow Log File Name" VALUE ="wf_HYB01_HONEYBADGER_DATE_ROLL.log"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Workflow Log File Directory" VALUE ="$PMWorkflowLogDir&#x5c;"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Save Workflow log by" VALUE ="By runs"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Save workflow log for these runs" VALUE ="$PMWorkflowLogCount"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Service Name" VALUE =""/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Service Timeout" VALUE ="0"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Is Service Visible" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Is Service Protected" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Fail task after wait time" VALUE ="0"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Enable HA recovery" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Automatically recover terminated tasks" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Service Level Name" VALUE ="Default"/>
```

Please help.

Comment: You want to use a XML interpreter for this. Doing it with shell scripting can be dreadful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Single liner sed command for this.

```
sed -i 's/<ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Automatically recover terminated tasks" VALUE ="NO"\/>/<ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Automatically recover terminated tasks" VALUE ="YES"\/>/g filename'
```

Where filename is sample file

Answer (score 0):

Open file in vi editor and use below: 
:%s/Old-Sentence/Replace-with-New-Sentence/g

If do not want to open file in vi the use below: 
sed -i -e 's/Old-Sentence/Replace-with-New-Sentence/g' filename